# Symfony & Doctrine - Repository or Doctrine cache to clear?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony-2.7

My environment :

- Symfony 2.7
- Custom Bundle "IpadBundle".
- Entity is "Checksum.php" and my controller is "MainController.php".

All work perfect when i Use the findAll() method on my repo. Then

- I added 2 new properties in my entity ($file_path and $creation_date)
- Getters and Setters were generated by *app/console doctrine:generate:entities IpadBundle:Checksum*
- Mysql database has been updated via doctrine:schema:update --force
- I went to my phpmyadmin to fill manually the 2 new cols

... but result of findAll() doesn't include these new cols ! I tried :

- cache:clear --env=prod
- cache:warmup
- "$cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();" + "$cacheDriver->deleteAll();"
- "app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata" + "app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query" +  "app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result".

But no results.
Any idea ?

Comment: can you provide us the annotations for these new fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes that happend to me and the only thing I do is restart apache and whola. Is weird IDK why apache saves some cache for entities, try it and let me know if that works for you. Good Luck !

Comment: You must be right, this morning my code is working fine then I guess APC or Apache cache have been clean up. However I can't do it myself to be 100% sure that's due to it. Thanks for your help !